# Changing Recent files submenu content at run time in WPF

Tags: wpf, dynamic, menu, runtime

I tried to create Recent files submenu in my application. My code was based on example from https://www.itcodar.com/csharp/wpf-how-to-create-menu-and-submenus-using-binding.html

When I tried to use static menu item in a manner like this:

```xml
<MenuItem Header="_File">
    <MenuItem Header="_Open..." Command="Open"/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Save..." Command="Save"/>
    <Separator></Separator>
    <MenuItem Header="_Close" Command="Close"/>
    <Separator></Separator>
    <MenuItem Header="_Recent Files">
        <Menu  DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
                </Style>
            </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Menu.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header }"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </Menu.ItemTemplate>
        </Menu>
    </MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```

by clicking this item I got horizontal menu to the left of opened menu instead of vertical one.

I placed this item in dynamic menu:

```xml
<MenuItem Header="_File">
    <MenuItem Header="_Open..." Command="Open"/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Save..." Command="Save"/>
    <Separator></Separator>
    <MenuItem Header="_Close" Command="Close"/>
    <Separator></Separator>
    <Menu  DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
        <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
            </Style>
        </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Menu.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header }"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemTemplate>
    </Menu>
</MenuItem>
```

I got vertical submenu beneath the opened menu. It's not precisely what I want but acceptable.
But the main problem occurs when I started my application - recent file list doesn't updated with newly opened files. It stays unchanged from the start of application.

So I'm interesting how could I update dynamic menu at run time, and, as handicap, how could I  place recent files list left of calling menu?

Comment: From your explanations it is not clear what relation the list of open files has to your code. At a minimum, you need to clarify what the MenuItems collection is. How its elements are implemented, how it is updated.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood you - English is not always easy for me to understand.
Do I understand you correctly now: the code in the link to itcodar is used by you without changes?

Comment: The example on itcodar is not very successful. It is poorly adapted to dynamic change. Rather, this is a kind of template approach to one of the implementation options. You can only use the idea itself, and not an exact copy of the code.

Comment: For practical use, you need to create a ViewModel with a property of type ObservableCollection containing the latest files. Then it can be displayed from the menu.

Comment: Excuse me. I thought that my C# code is obvious. I can't place it here. So I explain on the base of source example. In the MainWindow constructor I placed modified code from example. Suppose there is no modificftion. I get dinamic menu opened from main menu. In the run time I want to change content of this menu. I placed the same code in Open exception handler and make some changes in dynamic menu. But displaying menu after file opening doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```cs
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Simplified;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;

namespace Core2023.SO.Old_Nick.question77731533
{
    public class FilesViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<FileInfo> Files { get; } = new();

        public RelayCommand OpenFile => GetCommand(OpenFileExecute);
        public RelayCommand ReOpenFile => GetCommand<FileInfo>(OpenFileExecute);

        private void OpenFileExecute()
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                OpenFileExecute(new FileInfo(dialog.FileName));
        }
        private void OpenFileExecute(FileInfo fileInfo)
        {
            int index = Files.IndexOf(fileInfo);
            if (index < 0)
            {
                Files.Insert(0, fileInfo);
                while (Files.Count > 10)
                {
                    Files.RemoveAt(Files.Count - 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Files.Move(index, 0);
            }

            MessageBox.Show($"Open File: {fileInfo.FullName}");
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2023.SO.Old_Nick.question77731533.FilesWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023.SO.Old_Nick.question77731533"
        xmlns:io="clr-namespace:System.IO;assembly=System.IO.FileSystem"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="FilesWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:FilesViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="Open" Command="{Binding OpenFile}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Recent Files" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
                    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type io:FileInfo}">
                            <Button Content="{Binding FullName}"
                                Command="{Binding ReOpenFile, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource vm}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code uses my implementations of ViewModelBase and RelayCommand in space. You can replace them with the ones you are familiar with.
The remaining types are default for WPF with the target platform .Net6

Comment: Unfortunately I havedn't find TeamFoundation.Controls.dll on my computer. I tried to reinstall my Visual Studio but haven't find such item. How could I get it? And by the way. Should I simply replace class MenuItemViewModel with your class? Or I should do something else but edit XML file?

Comment: Except ViewModelBase and RelayCommand, all types are default for WPF with .Net6 target framework

Comment: @Old_Nick "MenuItemViewModel" is a class created to make the example easier to explain. In a real application, you need to replace it with one that performs the functions required for your application. Since your functions work with files, I called it FilesViewModel. But most likely this is only part of the functionality and you should name it according to the full functionality.

Comment: "TeamFoundation.Controls.dll" - used to create extensions for VisualStudio. You do it?

Comment: No, but according to MSDN it contains ViewModelBase realization.